# int LA[] = {1,2,3,4,5} memory allocation confusion in c

Tags: c, arrays, loops, memory

I have observed that memory allocated for array seems to be dynamic.

Here is the sample code I found in this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/array_data_structure.htm):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
   int LA[] = {1,3,5,7,8};
   int item = 10, k = 3, n = 5;
   int i = 0, j = n;

   printf("The original array elements are :\n");

   for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
      printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
   }

   n = n + 1;

   while( j >= k){
      LA[j+1] = LA[j];
      j = j - 1;
   }

   LA[k] = item;

   printf("The array elements after insertion :\n");

   for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
      printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
   }
}
```

and sample output:

> ```
> The original array elements are :
> LA[0]=1 
> LA[1]=3 
> LA[2]=5 
> LA[3]=7 
> LA[4]=8 
> The array elements after insertion :
> LA[0]=1 
> LA[1]=3 
> LA[2]=5 
> LA[3]=10 
> LA[4]=7 
> LA[5]=8
> ```

How its working I did not get.

Comment: It isn't "working". It's invoking *undefined behavior*, and as such, what you get for results is irrelevant.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the point of `n = n + 1;`?

Comment: please refer to the link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/array_data_structure.htm

Comment: @purplepsycho : that's what my doubt.:p

Comment: @Karunakar the example you linked is indeed what you posted here, and in my opinion grounds to squelch ever visiting that site again for tutoring. That posted code invokes *undefined behavior*, plain and simple. They're doing you a *tremendous* disservice by teaching you to program like that.

Comment: I second what @WhozCraig said. Stop visiting that site and blacklist it.

Comment: i know the problem. but , i wanted to know how its working in that site.

Comment: @SouravGhosh : thanks man

Comment: To: Karunakar,  Notice the use of  _"quotes"_ in the very first comment by @WhozCraig, and read the link in my answer to understand more about that.

Comment: In short: It works accidentally. There is no dynamic allocation.

Comment: The internet is full of crap. Like that site.

Comment: @Karunakar: *Most likely*, that code is writing to some unused "scratch" space or padding that's on the stack for alignment purposes. It *appears* to work because it isn't writing over anything important.  If you tried to add more than one object to the array, you would most likely corrupt data or have a runtime error.

Answer (score 5):

First, a general statement, for an array defined without explicit size and initialized using brace-enclosed initializer, the size will depend o the elements in the initializer list. So, for your array

```
 int LA[] = {1,3,5,7,8};
```

size will be `5`, as you have 5 elements.

C uses 0-based array indexing, so the valid access will be 0 to 4.

In your code

```
 LA[j+1] = LA[j];
```

trying to access index `6`, (`5+1`) which is out of bound access. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Output of a code having UB cannot be justified in any way.

---

That said, `main()` is technically an invalid signature as per latest C standards. You need to use at least `int main(void)` to make the code conforming for a hosted environment.

Comment: please refer to the source link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/array_data_structure.htm

Comment: @Karunakar simply change source to learn C. Someone who post such code should never teach C!

Comment: @Karunakar You should probably refer to another tutorial. The code you are linking to is just as wrong as yours.

Answer (score 2):

The code has a buffer overflow bug! Arrays in C cannot be extended! You need to allocate enough space when you declare/define it.

You can declare additional space by supplying a size in the declaration:

```
int LA[10] = {1,3,5,7,8};
```

`LA` will now have room for 10 elements with index 0 through 9.

If you want more flexibility you should use a pointer and `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` to allocate memory.

**Note:**

There is a second bug in the copying. The loop starts one step too far out.

With `j` starting at 5 and assigning index `j+1` the code assigns `LA[6]`, which is the 7th element. After the insertion there are only 6 elements.

My conclusion from these 2 bugs is that the tutorial was neither written nor reviewed by an experienced C programmer.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the other answers, C/C++ do not do any bounds checking for arrays.

In this case you have a stack allocated array, so as long as your index does not leave stack space, there will be no "errors" during runtime. However, since you are leaving the bounds of your array, it is possible that you may end up changing the values of other variables that are also allocated in the stack if it's memory location happens to be immediately after the allocated array. This is one of the dangers of buffer overflows and can cause very bad things to happen in more complex programs.